# How to stop sensative errors from displaying?

Tags: php, error-handling

I know that it would be a bad idea to completely disable errors from displaying (like by setting `error_reporting(0)`), but is there a way to stop system paths at the very least from showing on a live website?

Comment: production sites should not be displaying errors, period. leave error reporting on, but have them logged to a file instead of showing to the user. then have appropriate error handling that displays USEFUL error messages.

Comment: Don't show PHP errors to the user in production, show all errors (including notices) in development.

Comment: set `display_errors` off in your `php.ini` or some webserver context like a `.htaccess` or `httpd.conf` file in a virtualhost block. The problem with using ini_set() is it may not be applied with parse errors, and if you forget to put it in a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with having error_reporting on in your production environment, just make sure it is only showing in your logs by having `display_errors` set to off.

Answer (score 1):

You can leave error reporting on and use `ini_set('display_errors',0);` so that they will not be displayed but are still logged in the error log.